# Angular-ui routing issue

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that has two main sections and I have created routes for each section.

Everything was fine until after I added the second section and the additional routes to the config section of the app.  I am getting the error:

**Error: No reference point given for path '.blog'**

Here is the Angular app config.

```
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, embedlyServiceProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $stateProvider

 // SECTION 1
.state('blog', {
    abstract:true,
    url: '/blog',
    templateUrl: '../../../../views/projects/templates/blog.html',
    controller: 'projectController'
})


// nested states 
// each of these sections will have their own view
// url will be nested (/blog/updates)
.state('blog.updates', {
    url: '/updates',
    templateUrl: '../../../../views/projects/templates/updates.html',
})

.state('blog.comments', {
    url: '/comments',
    templateUrl: '../../../../views/projects/templates/comments.html',
})



   // SECTION 2
    .state('build', {
        url: '/build',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/build.html',
        controller: 'BuilderController'
    })

    // nested states 
    .state('build.basics', {
        url: '/basics',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/basics.html'
    })

    // url will be /build/products
    .state('build.products', {
        url: '/products',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/products.html'
    })
    .state('build.blog', {
        url: '/blog',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/blog.html'
    })
    .state('build.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/profile.html'
    })

    .state('build.payment', {
        url: '/payment',
        templateUrl: '../../views/forms/payment.html'
    })
    .state('build.team', {
        url: '/team',
        templateUrl: '../../views/projectbuilder/forms/team.html'
    });

// catch all route
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Here are the ui-srefs for the first section:

```
      <div class="row">
        <ul class="inline-list">
            <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".blog">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".updates">Updates ({{formData.updatesCount}})</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".comments">Comments ({{formData.commentsCount}})</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here are the ui-srefs for the second section.  This section is still working fine.

```
    <ul class="side-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".basics"><span>1</span> Basics</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".blog"><span>3</span> Blog</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".profile"><span>4</span> Profile</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".payment"><span>5</span> Payments</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref=".team"><span>6</span> Team</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Thanks for any insight into this.  I am fairly new at Angular and still getting my head around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to angular-ui [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref):

> ui-sref = 'stateName' can be any valid absolute or relative state

Remove the dots and use the unique state names as configured in the state router.

Don't forget blog state is abstract.

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated
>   itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be
>   transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its
>   descendants are activated.

Angular-UI documentation on [nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views) (including abstract usages)

```
<div class="row">
        <ul class="inline-list">
            <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="blog.updates">Updates ({{formData.updatesCount}})</a></li>
            <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="blog.comments">Comments ({{formData.commentsCount}})</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Or Guz but it is not solving the issue.  I removes the dots as suggested and it produces same error.  Adding state name to ui-sref gave a new error Error: Could not resolve 'updates' from state ''.  If I remove SECTION 1 the SECTION 2 and corresponding ui-srefs work.

Comment: You used the full state name as written in my code? blog.updates?

Comment: Yes..  I got the javascript error to stop but now the templates are not switching now with no error given.  Any ideas on that?  I will mark your answer for sure as it did solve the original problem.  Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5qb6kose/  This will help you, enjoy. I wrote a working jsfiddle to make an example for your need, didn't find any good one online